# ASP.net MVC - RestSharp POST complex object is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.net MVC 4 WebAPI. I have another ASP.net MVC application which is posting to the Web API in Controller. However, when I pass the Complex object, the Complex object property goes null in the ASP.net MVC 4 Web API.

## WEB API Code

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetProdctPrice([FromBody]User user) // user object is null
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

## ASP.NET MVC Consumer Code

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = new User()
        {
            Name = "Headphone",
            Product = new Product() { Age = 33 }
        };

        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:56013/api/";

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.Resource = "/Products/GetProdctPrice";
        request.AddObject(user);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        ViewBag.Message = response.Content;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: are u sure, your request has the Product and User detail. use fiddler and check your request body

Comment: should you not be using something like: request.AddParameter("User",user)

Answer (score 0):

**Rename your GetProdctPrice to PostProdctPrice.**

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {


       // [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public string PostProdctPrice(User user) 
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

In WebAPI(when you inherit your controller from APiController) you don't need to add [HttpPost] or [HttpGet]  attributes on top of your methods. Any method which starts with Get is automatically mapped with the HTTP GET method, any method that starts with Post is automatically mapped with the HTTP POST method.